# Software not showing up in "activities"

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 17.10, spotify, slack

I've installed a couple of apps (Slack and Spotify) from "Software" and while they run fine the first time, they don't show up in search when I go to "Activities" so I can't launch them except by going back through the software app. They don't even show up on my $PATH, which is weird.

Comment: Interesting, could be. I've also found https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/snap-install-programs-not-in-launcher which I'll try when I get back to my PC.

Comment: Also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374959