# Snaps suddenly missing from Launcher and PATH

Tags: launcher, snap

All of my snaps that *used* to be available on the command line and in my launcher are suddenly missing, despite still being installed and enabled:

```
➜ snap list
Name                    Version                  Rev   Developer     Notes
auryo                   1.4.3                    10    snapcrafters  -
clion                   2017.3.3                 6     jetbrains     classic
core                    16-2.30                  3887  canonical     core
gnome-3-26-1604         3.26.0                   27    canonical     -
inkscape                0.92.2                   3080  inkscape      -
intellij-idea-ultimate  2017.3.4                 23    jetbrains     classic
kde-frameworks-5        5.42.0                   16    kde           -
minetest                0.4.16                   7     snapcrafters  -
peek                    1.2.2                    711   phw           -
pycharm-professional    2017.3.3                 47    jetbrains     classic
spotify                 1.0.70.399.g5ffabd56-26  5     spotify       -
supertuxkart            0.9.3                    2     diddledan     -
webstorm                2017.3.4                 10    jetbrains     classic
```

They worked just yesterday, and all I've changed is my default shell (zsh now, instead of bash). My PATH variable is exactly the same and there is nothing missing from my .zshrc that is present in my .bashrc that could affect this as far as I can tell.

How do I get my snaps accessible again?

Comment: Is `/snap/bin` in your path?

Comment: @Terrance no, but my original .bashrc didn't have any explicit instruction to add it to my path, either, so I figure some other thing is failing to add it in that used to.

Comment: I am looking into this one as one of my systems has it in the path somewhere, but it is not in the `.bashrc` or the `.profile` so I am looking for that one.  The other system that doesn't have it at one point I had it added to the `/etc/environment` file, but it looks as though that was overwritten.  Searching for the answer on this.

Comment: @Terrance I found it in /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh. Adding `source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` to my .zshrc. Now I guess my only problem is the launcher,.

Comment: Good find.  Unfortunately, that doesn't explain though why they are missing from the launcher though.

Comment: My work system here is in the same boat.  All the snaps stopped working and the path won't even stay for some reason.  Almost like the `/etc/profile` is not loading at startup.  Plus, I am getting `execl failed: No such file or directory` when I try to run any of them.  Looking to see if I can find anything on this and why now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version does `snap version` say it is?  If you could edit your question and add that information.

Comment: @Terrance ➜ snap version
snap    2.30
snapd   2.30
series  16
neon    16.04
kernel  4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programs installed via snap not showing up in Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/programs-installed-via-snap-not-showing-up-in-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting this snap bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1640514

A workaround is to explicitly source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh in your .zshrc or .zshenv.