# Kubuntu 19.10: Snap Apps Missing

Tags: snap

I installed multiple snap apps in Kubuntu 19.10 which functioned normally for a couple of weeks until today. Now when I open snap apps from the dock, icons have a question mark and when opened, the error message is:  `Unknown application folder`

When I search for the snap apps in the menu, none show. However, when I do `snap list`, all the snap applications are listed.  In the terminal, [kdenlive](https://www.mankier.com/1/kdenlive) appears to be installed. When I search for the application, it doesn't appear, only the snap directory for the application appears.

How may I troubleshoot this?

[image: Missing snap apps]

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us which version of Linux you are using (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) and the version number. Please do not click on Add Comment; instead, put that vital info in your question.

Comment: There's a known bug described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006916/snaps-suddenly-missing-from-launcher-and-path with a fix. please try that and let us know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to restart my computer - three times that is. Snap apps are working properly now.