# Snap-installed app doesn't put icon into launcher

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, snap, plasma-5

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on a reasonably fresh install. I've installed a few snap applications, but none of their icons will show up in my launcher.

I had a previous install of Kubuntu 18.04 that I upgraded from 17.10 and these same apps (also installed by snap) would show the icons.

I'm assuming it's something with how I'm installing/running the snap-based apps, but I'm not sure what to look at next.

```
% snap list
Name    Version            Rev   Tracking  Publisher     Notes
core    16-2.36.3          6130  stable    canonical✓    core
core18  18                 536   stable    canonical✓    base
slack   3.3.3              9     stable    slack✓        classic
vscode  1.30.0-1544567151  72    stable    snapcrafters  classic
```

What's the next thing I should look into to troubleshoot?

Like I mentioned, I'm pretty new to Linux on the desktop. I tried symlinking `/usr/share/applications/slack.desktop` to `/snap/slack/9/usr/share/applications/slack.desktop` but that didn't seem to do anything

Here is what is in `/snap/slack/9/usr/share/applications/slack.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Slack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=/usr/bin/slack %U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/slack;
```

Any advice on what to look into next? I'm not sure if it's a snap issue or a KDE/Plasma issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programs installed via snap not showing up in Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/programs-installed-via-snap-not-showing-up-in-launcher)

Answer (score 23):

I found the answer. It's not Plasma/KDE or snap, but zsh. I'm not sure why this worked on my old setup as I was using zsh there as well without a workaround.

This answer solved my problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/989485/754993.

To quote:

> If you are using zsh, the snap binary and desktop directories will not automatically be added to your environment variables.

The step I did specifically was to add `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'` to the bottom of my `/etc/zsh/zprofile` file.

Comment: Great answer, its worked for me

Comment: That is so weird! Why would zsh have anything to do with what appears in *any* desktop environment in the first place?

Comment: thank you, issue solved!

Answer (score 4):

Solved it by adding "/snap/bin" path to `/etc/environment` file.