# Undefined X icon on Latte dock

Tags: 18.04, icons, dock

**Kubuntu 18.04, latte 0.7.4-0ubuntu2**

Hi, I've got an annoying issue with "X" icons if an application is closed. It happens only with few apps (slack and mailspring in my example). Reinstall doesn't help.

**Apps are closed**

[image: Apps are closed]

**When I run the slack app, an icon appears**

[image: When I run the slack an icon appears]

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are these snaps?

Comment: Please ask at [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/search?q=latte&restrict_sr=1); the developer of Latte Dock is quite active there. If you get a solution there, you could come back here and post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: And if these applications are snaps, see if anything in https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/snap-install-programs-not-in-launcher helps.