# Missing software that are installed in system

Tags: software-center, gnome-shell, snap, zsh, installed-programs

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I am running with an issue. Some of the packages installed using the default Software store application like Postman, Spotify are somehow are not showing in app tray but are showing installed in Software Store. Also, I can run them from there.

Moreover, when I launch Spotify and Login it's showing some firewall error (may be helpful to find the bug).

I just noticed one thing, all the application installed from snap are not showing in app tray. The output of `snap list` is given below.

[image]

I installed `zsh` yesterday,

Comment: @PRATAP from default ubuntu app store

Comment: I just installed Spotify from Ubuntu Software and as soon as it is installed.. it showed in all apps.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/90BlR.png

Comment: just noticed one thing...all the application installed from snap are not showing in app tray...not reinstalling them is working

Comment: can you have a look on this? https://askubuntu.com/q/910821/739431

Comment: yes i did install zsh yesterday