# Ubuntu 19.04. Symlink of app installed with snap disappear when rebooting

Tags: 19.04

I just made a fresh installation of ubuntu 19.04. Join with wayland. I install vscode and postman via snap. all good, after about 10 minutes of use, restart, upon returning, the symlinks of both applications disappeared.

Comment: fix for this: https://askubuntu.com/a/989485/946199

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programs installed via snap not showing up in Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910821/programs-installed-via-snap-not-showing-up-in-launcher)